# DefaultNetworkCredentials not working from crm

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, defaultnetworkcredentials

I'm making a CRM 2011 workflow activity that is supposed to create folders in a given SharePoint.  I am doing this by calling "MKCOL" method of HttpWebRequest.

Before making my code into a workflow activity, I made a console app that uses DefaultNetworkCredentials and it worked (the folders appeared in SharePoint).  However, after converting my code into a workflow activity and running it from CRM, it no longer works.

Besides switching the class to inherit from CodeActivity, I didn't change the HttpWebRequest code.

I was under the impression the DefaultNetworkCredentials would use my (the current user's) credentials, so why do my credentials no longer work in CRM?

Thanks for any help,
  Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflows run under the Async Worfklow service, not the user that is actually triggering the service.  You'll need to set the credentials in code, or [update the account that runs the service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699751.aspx).

Comment: Changing the service accounts is indeed supported (and pretty straight forward): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699751.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JamesWood.  Updated my answer to reflect your comment.